# Use of 'she' in scientific literature

Tags: research, hci

While reading through plenty of scientific papers for my thesis relating to Human Computer Interaction (HCI), I am under the impression almost everybody refers to users/subjects/persons/... as 'she'.

A [quick check on English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/876/tendency-of-using-pronouns-she-her-when-talking-about-a-random-person) indicates this is a relatively new trend *"to balance out the perceived sexism"*.

Is this default or recommended in recent scientific HCI papers?

---

UPDATE: So perhaps English.SE can help me out. It seems like [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/28508) is already more on topic.

Comment: Well, I have found that while it may be an attempt to balance out the sexism, another one has been introduced by it. When talking about users not reading messages and other behaviour you need to design around, quite often "she" is used. While when talking about smart design(er)s, or program(mer)s "he" tends to get used... But then again, maybe my gender is making me more sensitive to these things and I don't notice the occurences where it is the other way round... :-)

Comment: It seems like you already got your answer on english.se

Comment: oh man - - closed just as I put a UX slant on the answer :-)

Comment: @Roger: I was posting a UX answer as well as I don't really see how closing this as off-topic would help anyone in the future. In what way is this off-topic? Since it _also_ applies to language? I tried closing as duplicate of the question on English.SE but this wasn't possible. P.s.: I guess the real answer to my question is *"no"*.

Comment: Ok I have changed my mind and voted to reopen. The feedback started to take a UX turn, although initially the question seemed slightly off topic and already answered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tend to deliberately avoid the situation with a variety of alternatives, including, but not limited to `the user` and `they`. And in any case, it simplifies the issue a bit because once you use `he` or `she` you have to concern yourself with use of `his`, `her`, `hers`, etc.

I am not alone:

The [Microsoft user experience guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx) is about 880 pages and refers to `he` in just one sentence, `she` in just two different sentences, and `he or she` in just one. But `the user` is used 550 times and `they` 384 times

The [Apple Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Intro/Intro.html) does not use `he` or `she` once in some 280 pages but `the user` comes up about 445 times and `they` 835 times.

[Those figures are adjusted to exclude `the user` when used as part of the term `the user experience`]

I can't speak for scientific writing generally, but I do find it 'of note' these days when a text chooses to use `she` *or* `he`. I don't see that choosing the opposite of `he` really addresses the balance so much as tries to overcompensate for what I agree has been an imbalance in the past.

**But you are asking an audience that is probably somewhat biased towards `the user`** !!

Comment: Can we determine from this that Apple is more than twice as concerned as Microsoft about the user, because the 'per page' usage of the term 'the user' in their ux guidelines outweighs the other by two and a half times...?

Comment: No, that would be stretching statistics a bit :-). I don't think one can glean "concern" from frequency of use. Maybe they just are a teensy bit OCD in their use of the term...

Comment: I just bumped into this issue, and realize this is not really a solution at all. How do I refer to 'the user'? As 'his' or 'her'? Or always use plural and refer to 'their'? E.g. _"doesn't support the user in managing **his** activities"_.

Comment: it becomes the indefinite singular or generic possessive form (or something like that!) of they - ie 'doesn't support the user in managing *their* activities'.

Comment: @Steven Jeuris - see this wikipedia article on [singular they](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they)

Comment: @Roger: Thanks, but I already read that article, hence [my answer](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10097/use-of-she-in-scientific-literature/10110#10110). The _acceptability_ chapter didn't really make things clearer for me. :/

Comment: @Steven - certainly the question of acceptance of singular they seems to be unclear and there are arguments for and against. See also [discussion on english.se](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192/is-it-correct-to-use-their-instead-of-his-or-her). There are alternatives if you're not happy - eg avoiding the issue 'doesn't support managing the user's activities' - or using the plural:  'doesn't support the users in managing their activities', acceptance of which seems to be undisputed. Either way, there's no need to fall back to his or her and introduce a gender where none is needed.

Answer (score 2):

No, this **is not default** in scientific writing. The [wikipedia article on 'singular they'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) sheds some light on the issue.

> In the late 20th century, the feminist movement expressed concern
>   regarding the use of generic he in the English language. The feminist
>   claim was that such usage contributes to an assumption that maleness
>   is "standard," and that femaleness is "different". They also claimed
>   that such use is misogynistic. One response to this was an increase in
>   the use of generic she in academic journal articles from around this
>   time.

There are a lot of discussions about this subject, but no standards have been defined for scientific writing as far as I have searched. Some people might approve of [singular they](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they), while others might frown upon its usage.

As stated in Roger's answer, a safe bet is to work around this issue by refering to 'the user' instead of she or he.